# Flutter SecureSocketServer transfer

Tags: flutter, dart, networking, openssl, tls1.3

I run my code on 2 devices, one server one client, I want to secure the transfer, the transfer is going on in a local network (someone else can listen).

That's why I created self-signed certificate and a key to initialize my server.

```
    var ctx = SecurityContext()
            ..useCertificateChainBytes(utf8.encode(Secure.cer))
            ..usePrivateKeyBytes(utf8.encode(Secure.key));
          
socketServer = await SecureServerSocket.bind(hostAddress, Global.unusedPort, ctx,shared: true);
```

and on Client:

```
      var ctx = SecurityContext()
            ..useCertificateChainBytes(utf8.encode(Secure.cer))
            ..usePrivateKeyBytes(utf8.encode(Secure.key));
          
connectedSocket = await SecureSocket.connect(device.ipAddress, device.port!,context: ctx);
```

Secure.key and Secure.cer are static Strings which have the certificate and the key.

When I try to send messages between I always get:

```
flutter: ----------------------------------------------------
flutter: HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake
```

I don't what to do next, how can I secure the transfer between? I don't want to encrypt the messages because I am sending file bytes between.

Comment: On the client, no need for the two `..useXXX` - instead use `..badCertificateCallback` and return true.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by adding Richard's answer to the code.

On client side I only need to add defaultContext and return true for every badCertificateCallback. In my case I did not return true directly. I compared the self-signed certificate which created by me and both devices have that certificate inside.

```
  var ctx = SecurityContext.defaultContext;

  Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(Secure.cerContext);
  connectedSocket = await SecureSocket.connect(ipAddress, port,context: ctx, onBadCertificate: (X509Certificate cert) {
    return const ListEquality().equals(bytes, cert.der);
  });
```

I think that this approach will be better for me to secure against man in the middle attacks as long as the app is not reverse engineered and certificate is not stolen.

Comment: In other words by making it insecure again. This is not the answer. The answer is to ensure that both peers recognize each other's certificates. The time involved in making self-signed certificates work correctly is simply not worth it compared to the relatively trivial cost of using CA-signed certificates.

Comment: I did not understand. @user207421 why does it not work? I mean both devices have the same certificate, and the client checks if the cerfiticates are same with the server and it is. What's wrong here, I am asking because I do not know.